# Getting a dotted font from a regular font

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts

I have a need to take a regular font and obtain a dotted version of it. By "dotted", I mean that the lines and curves that make up the letterforms are composed of dots or dashes [MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/dotted/fonts/) has some examples of what I mean.

Is there any way to convert an existing non-dotted font into a dotted font without having to use a font editor myself?

Comment: Times are changing... the truetype is a regular and dotted is irregular)) Sorry, I have no info on your question, just was not able to keep myself quiet

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "dotted"? A graphic showing what you consider "regular" and "dotted" would really help.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like he's talking about the ellipsis that occur when some label/etc. is shortened..? Screenshot appreciated.

Comment: "Dotted" is a fairly standard term for a font. So, for example, http://www.myfonts.com/search/dotted/fonts/ will provide a bunch of dotted fonts. A font called "Print Clearly" has both a dotted and a solid version - http://www.bvfonts.com/fonts/search.php?find=print+clearly

Comment: @Serge dotted true type or dotted Unicode is may be standard? Actually I unable to understand your comment. Please add some info if possible.

Comment: @MadhavNikam don't muddle the encoding standard (the Unicode) and glyph description technology (the TrueType). The OP meant a raster representation of a font.